# Is there a way to have a appscript use a spreadsheet owned by one person to look up data as another user?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my current code:

```
function doGet() { 
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('When Am I Eligible?');
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setHeight("400px").setWidth("400px");
//var submitButton = app.createButton('Check');


var key= '???'
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET');
  var last=ss.getLastRow();
  var data=sh.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();
  var valB= Session.getEffectiveUser();
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][1]==valB){
      var final = data[nn][0]
      break} ;// if a match in column B is found, break the loop
      }
// var finish = data[nn][0];
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 //var statusLabel = app.createLabel().setVisible(true).setText(String.valueOf(finish))
 var answer = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final)
 panel.add(answer);
 app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

It runs fine under me, but if someone else logged in under our domain uses it, it says they need to have the spreadsheet shared with them. The nature of the spreadsheet prevents this. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround in such a situation by writing two scripts.

Script 1: 
This is the script that is runs as you and accesses the spreadsheet. Something like

```
function doGet(e){
  var key= '0Anzdf0g-SCsDdDF1WEVrYjZyclIzMkdmZjVYUTdXN2c'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET');
  var last=ss.getLastRow();
  var data=sh.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();

  var valB = e.parameter.user; //Read it from e.

  for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][1]==valB){
      var final = data[nn][0]
      break} ;// if a match in column B is found, break the loop
      }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(final);
}
```

Script 2:
This script runs as the user running the UI where you call script 1

```
function doGet() { 
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('When Am I Eligible?');
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setHeight("400px").setWidth("400px");
//var submitButton = app.createButton('Check');

var final = UrlFetchApp.fetch('URL OF SCRIPT 1 PUBLISHED AS A SERVICE');
// var finish = data[nn][0];
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 //var statusLabel = app.createLabel().setVisible(true).setText(String.valueOf(finish))
 var answer = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final)
 panel.add(answer);
 app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is no.

One possible workaround is to store data in scriptdB that is linked to the script and therefor inherit the access rights of the app.

That database should be filled with data from the source spreadsheet and re-synchronized every time the spreadsheet is modified (this process can be automatically done with some triggers in the spreadsheet)

Of course it will implies a few deep changes in your script but it is worth the pain to guarantee data privacy.

As a very simple example here is a small code I use to get data from a SS with 2 columns :

```
function getlistFromSS(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var last =  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]).getLastRow();
  var list = sh.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues(); 
  var key = [] ; var value = []
  deleteDb()
    for(cc=0;cc<list.length;++cc){
      key.push(list[cc][0]);
      value.push(list[cc][1]);
      }
    for(cc=0;cc<key.length;++cc){
      var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb()
      db.save({name:key[cc], url:value[cc]})    
        Logger.log(key[cc]+'   '+value[cc])
      }
    }
```

Comment: I believe I fixed it, it seemse when I set the share settings of the spreadsheet to anyone with a link within the domain, those within the domain accessing the page see the script run correctly without it being added to their drive.

Thank you for the help though. =)

Comment: This is sadly an illusion... a smart user can quite easily find the url of the spreadsheet :-/

Comment: Thats true, but with my user's, I'm betting those who suffer from device envy wont be the same ones trying to find out what others have or have the capability to do so. Also, its embedded in a Google site, thereby adding a level of abstraction by having it published as a gadget tot the site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed it, it seemse when I set the share settings of the spreadsheet to anyone with a link within the domain, those within the domain accessing the page see the script run correctly without it being added to their drive. Thank you for the help though.